# Expression for the Clarke subdifferential of a weakly convex function

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, non-smooth-analysis

Let $\gamma\in\left]0,+\infty\right[$, let $f$ be a proper, convex, lower semicontinuous function from a real Hilbert space $\mathcal{X}$ to $\left]-\infty,+\infty\right]$, and set $g=f-\frac{\gamma}{2}\|\cdot\|^2$. Then $g$ is weakly convex.

I'm looking for a reference characterizing for which $x\in\mathcal{X}$ the following holds

\begin{equation}
\partial_{Clarke} g(x) = \partial_{convex} f(x) - \gamma x. \tag{*}
\end{equation}

where $\partial_{Clarke}$ is the Clarke subdifferential,

$$\partial_{convex} f(x) = \left\{ u \in \mathcal{X} \mid (\forall y \in \mathcal{X}) \quad \langle y - x \mid u \rangle + f(x)\leq f(y) \right\},$$

and the righthand side in (*) denotes Minkowski subtraction. I know that $(\nabla \frac{\gamma}{2}\|\cdot\|^2) (x) = \gamma x$ and that $\partial_{convex}$ coincides with $\partial_{Clarke}$ on convex functions. However, I am only working with a weakly convex function. I've perused Rockafellar/Wets but not found much.

I'm actually not entirely positive that (*) is true everywhere, e.g. it may fail on the boundary of the domain of $g$. Any relevant info is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I think it would suffice to find a reference for when the sum rule holds for Clarke subdifferentials. I believe that $\partial_{Clarke}g(x)\supset\partial_{convex}f(x)-\gamma x$, so it would suffice to show the reverse inclusion.

Comment: Rockafellar is the closest to this topic than other references. Maybe you can try this reference https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589712?seq=1

Comment: My comment might be obvious or useless, but I think (*) holds at least at the points where $f$ is locally Lipschitz. I used Corollary 5.4 of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11228-007-0043-y since you're in a reflexive space and $g$ is differentiable... I'm not sure, though.

Comment: Clarke’s book Nonlinear Analysis has the sum rule for the generalized gradient that can be used here

Comment: @NeutralElement thanks for the suggestion, I think the sum rule is exactly what I'm looking for! I'm not sure if I've got the right book, but I'm looking at Theorem 8.10 from *Nonlinear Analysis, Diff. Eq's and Control* and it looks like only of an approximate sum-rule. It does not show the equality (*) for the same $x$, it shows approximate equality for something in a neighborhood of $x$. Is this the result you were referring to?

Comment: @Zim Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis Thm 2.9.8, p. 102

Comment: @NeutralElement Ah ha, this is just the result I needed! Thank you so much! If you leave this as an answer to the question I can select it and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Zim Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis Thm 2.9.8, p. 102